# ng-grid lost sync with underlying data

Tags: ng-grid

I am updating a row of grid data from a jQeuryUI pop up form. After using Ajax updated server side database, I updated the row of data in data array. but the grid still stays unchanged. It seems the arry and the grid lost sync.

```
           $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: "/api/WebAPIAdminStaff",
                data: $('#editForm').serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        var scope = angular.element($("#ngBody")).scope();
                        var row = scope.gridOptions.selectedItems[0];
                        var index = scope.myData.indexOf(row);
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.myData[index].FirstName = paramFromView.FirstName;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Is anyting wrong with this code? Really need it working! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to end up with delete the row and add a new row again with updated data.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: "/api/WebAPIAdminStaff",
                data: $('#editForm').serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        var scope = angular.element($("#ngBody")).scope();
                        var row = scope.gridOptions.selectedItems[0];
                        var index = scope.myData.indexOf(row);
                        scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.myData.splice(index, 1);
                        });
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.myData.splice(index, 0, result);
                        });
                        setTimeout(selectARow, 0); 
                        function selectARow() {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);
                            });
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
```